# So... what is your StackOverflow score?

Tags: code-golf, stack-exchange-api

This is a simple one. Given the input of a number, return the name and reputation score of the Stack Overflow user with that **given ID**. Your program can assume that it is always given a valid and existent user ID.

For example: given the input `764357` (which is my userID on StackOverflow) the program would return `LegoStormtroopr 3,088` (approximately) it might change.

You get the URL: "https://stackoverflow.com/users/" or "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/" for free, so your score is `length of your program - 31 or 39`, **depending on which URL you use - but declare which it is**. This prevents people from abusing URL shorteners.

edit: And no calling a custom made API that query Stack Overflow, and returns just the name and score. <del>But if you know of an offical API, then that is totally legitimate.</del>

edit2: If you need an example input: I've given my ID below, feel free to add your own ID, username and score below to help others out. Note again, this is for the main Stack Overflow site.

```
764357   returns   LegoStormtroopr 3,088
```

Comment: hmm... if there are multiple users with that rep, should we pick one, or display all of them? What if there is no such user?

Comment: uh... wait... of the user with that score, or of the user with that ID?

Comment: @JanDvorak I've tried to clarify. The program should accept a user ID, and return the user with that ID, and that users Rep. Score.

Comment: The question still says "return the name and reputation score of the Stack Overflow user with that **score**."

Comment: @WolframH Wow, I am dumb and missed that **twice**. Fixed now. I hope.

Comment: Should the url `http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/` also be "free" to avoid penalising users of the API?

Comment: @gnibbler yes, you can get the official API for free.

Comment: Could we get the `site=stackoverflow` part for free too?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Sure. Why not

Answer (score 15):

## Shell script: <s>64</s> 51 characters

```sh
curl -sL http://stackoverflow.com/users/`cat`|grep -oPm2 'n">\K[0-9,]+|e">\K[^<]+'
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ curl -sL http://stackoverflow.com/users/`cat`|grep -oPm2 'n">\K[0-9,]+|e">\K[^<]+'
662504
manatwork
834

bash-4.1$ curl -sL http://stackoverflow.com/users/`cat`|grep -oPm2 'n">\K[0-9,]+|e">\K[^<]+'
764357
Lego Stormtroopr
3,087
```

(Note that you have to press `^D` after typing in the input interactively. Or just pipe it to the command.)

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby: <s>84</s> 70 characters

```ruby
s=open("http://stackoverflow.com/users/"+gets).read
puts s[/me">(.+)</,1],s[/n">([\d,]+)/,1]
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -ropen-uri -e 's=open("http://stackoverflow.com/users/"+gets).read;puts s[/me">(.+)</,1],s[/n">([\d,]+)/,1]' <<< '662504'
manatwork
834

bash-4.1$ ruby -ropen-uri -e 's=open("http://stackoverflow.com/users/"+gets).read;puts s[/me">(.+)</,1],s[/n">([\d,]+)/,1]' <<< '764357'
Lego Stormtroopr
3,087
```

Comment: You don't need full words in the regex: `s[/me">(.+)</,1],s[/ation".*?([\d,]+)/,1]` seems to work

Comment: Correct. They were just taken from my [shell script answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12720). (`grep` would display more matches for just “ation"”.)

Comment: @Doorknob, probably you omitted the `-ropen-uri` option. (It's mandatory and included in the character count.)

Comment: @manatwork Ah, didn't notice that. Okay now it works.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2.7 - 119

#### (150 - 31)

Without regex:

```
from urllib import*
s=urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/users/%d"%input()).read()
p=str.split 
print p(p(s,'r ')[1],' -')[0],p(p(s,'ore">')[1],'<')[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, 117

`117 = 148 - 31`

I don't think searching in plain HTML source code will lead to strong solution. For example, some weird stuff in one's profile may break your solutions. So I'd like to search using CSS selectors.

```
from lxml.html import*
C=parse('http://stackoverflow.com/users/'+input()).getroot().cssselect
print(C('[id^=u]')[0].text,C('[class$=ore]')[0].text)
```

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript 217

Heres a ungolfed Javascript Version using the official api with JSONP, to start with . Using the url would require XHR, which sould be quite verbose, if i find some time i'll try a more golfed version though.

```
d=document;function f(a){y=a.items[0];alert(y.display_name+" "+y.reputation)}x=d.createElement("script");x.src="https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/"+prompt()+"?site=stackoverflow&callback=f";d.body.appendChild(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

### Perl 5 (with Mojolicious), 87 - 31 = 56 bytes

```perl
say/h1.*>(.*)</,$/,/core">(.*?)</ for g("http://stackoverflow.com/users/".pop)->dom
```

Sample run:

```perl
$ perl -Mojo -E 'say/h1.*>(.*)</,$/,/core">(.*?)</ for g("http://stackoverflow.com/users/".pop)->dom' 764357
Lego Stormtroopr
3,103
```

Readable & clean: 128 - 31 = 97 bytes

```perl
say $_->at("#user-displayname")->text, ": ", $_->at(".reputation a")->text for g("http://stackoverflow.com/users/".pop)->dom
```

Sample run:

```perl
$ perl -Mojo -E 'say $_->at("#user-displayname")->text, ": ", $_->at(".reputation a")->text for g("http://stackoverflow.com/users/$ARGV[0]")->dom' 764357
Lego Stormtroopr: 3,103
```

Comment: Is `-Mojo` included in the count? That costs 4 characters.

Comment: @manatwork: No, I did not include it in the count, because the Ruby answer did not include `-ropen-uri`. However, I am happy to include it if your comment gets a few up votes as indication that the community wants to count these.

Comment: Count again. It includes. http://pastebin.com/qZp1QgKa

Comment: @manatwork: Oh, I was wrong. The Ruby answer does include -ropen-uri. So I will include it as well, adding 6 chars to both solutions.

Comment: Well, I wish we have an exact documentation of the counting rule, but as I know, there is none. One thing is sure: `perl`'s `-p` option is usually counted +1. Based on that I count `-Mojo` +4.

Comment: @manatwork: OK I see. I am very new to the codegolf site and will edit the answer once again. Thank you.

Comment: if parameters to the interp costs nothing, what about `-e codehere`?

Comment: Here's [one set of rules](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/199) we've been using a few times.

Answer (score 4):

### R: 150-31=119

```
f=function(i){S=function(x)strsplit(grep(x,scan(paste0("http://stackoverflow.com/users/",i),"",sep="\n"),v=T)[1],">|<")[[1]][3];cat(S("h1"),S("=re"))}
```

Quite simply picks the first lines containing `h1` (for the name) and `=re` (for the score) using `grep` with argument `value=TRUE` (here `v=T`) and then split the string (using `strsplit` at characters `>` and `<`. Inconveniently it queries the page twice (hence the two "Read n items" warnings) but that was shorter.

```
>f(1451109)
Read 917 items
Read 917 items
plannapus 6,566
```

Answer (score 4):

### Tcl, (231 - 39) 192

not the shortest way, but using the official API

```
package r http
package r json
set d [lindex [dict get [json::json2dict [http::data [http::geturl http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/$argv?site=stackoverflow]]] items] 0]
puts [dict get $d display_name]\ [dict get $d reputation]
```

And in spirit of the **original** question:

```
package r http
package r json
set c [dict get [json::json2dict [http::data [http::geturl http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&min=$argv&max=$argv]]] items]
foreach d $c {puts "[dict get $d display_name] [dict get $d reputation]"}
```

Finds users with that reputation

Comment: Sorry about that mixup!

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: I wrote this answer when it was clear that you mean the userid, but I liked to show that the official API is able to solve the original question too.

Answer (score 3):

## Shorter CoffeeScript: 143 characters (182 - 39)

This relies on the API always returning the object keys in the same order, but shaves off 7 characters.

```coffeescript
f=(r)->u=Object.keys(items[0]);alert u[3]+' '+u[5]
d=document
j=d.createElement('script')
j.src="//api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/"+prompt()+'?site=diy&jsonp=f'
d.body.appendChild j
```

## CoffeeScript: 150 characters (189 - 39)

```coffeescript
f=(r)->u=r.items[0];alert u.display_name+' '+u.reputation
d=document
j=d.createElement('script')
j.src="//api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/"+prompt()+'?site=diy&jsonp=f'
d.body.appendChild j
```

(Note that the program prompts you for "undefined" -- it's asking for the User ID.)

Answer (score 3):

### R - 84

84 = 115 - 31

```
sub(".*\\/(.*)\\?.*>(.*)<.*","\\1 \\2",grep("b=r",scan(paste0("http://stackoverflow.com/users/",scan(n=1)),""),v=T)[1])
```

Simulation:

```
> sub(".*\\/(.*)\\?.*>(.*)<.*","\\1 \\2",grep("b=r",scan(paste0("http://stackoverflow.com/users/",scan(n=1)),""),v=T)[1])
1: 1201032
Read 1 item
Read 2976 items
[1] "flodel 31,093"
```

Comment: +1 This is a very impressive use of regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

### <strike>101</strike> 100 - CoffeeScript with jQuery

```
$.getJSON "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/#{prompt()}?site=stackoverflow",(d)->alert [d.items[0].reputation,d.items[0].display_name]
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brigand/txnfa/); just know that it prompts you when you first open the page, so have a ID ready, or press Run again.

Or we can be super hacky to save a whole character!

```
$.getJSON "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/#{prompt()}?site=stackoverflow",(d)->`with(d.items[0])alert([reputation,display_name])`;1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7 - 112

#### 112 = 143 - 31

A newer, short version that uses some of the ideas from [Steven Rumbalski answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12728/8777), while still using Regex.

```
import urllib,re
r=re.findall('r (.*?) -|re">(.*?)<',urllib.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/users/%d"%input()).read())
print r[0][0],r[2][1]
```

#### 133 = 164 - 31

Here is a base version for people to work from, but I'm sure people can get even shorter.

```
import urllib,re
u=input()
s=urllib.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/users/%d"%u).read()
r=re.findall('name.*?>(.*?)</h1|tion.?>(.*?)</a',s)
print r[0][0],r[1][1]
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. `http://stackoverflow.com/users/12340` is 404.

Comment: @JanDvorak, try with `499214` instead of `12340`

Comment: @PeterTaylor then the question is incorrect.

Comment: @JanDvorak Obviously, the user with that ID doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

## GNU Awk: 217 characters

Just because GNU `awk` supports TCP natively: no module/library/external tool.

```awk
{RS="\r"
print h("/users/"$0,$0,"/",4),h($2,$2"\\?","<|>",3)}function h(p,m,r,f){d="stackoverflow.com"
g="/inet/tcp/0/"d"/80"
print"GET "p" HTTP/1.1\nHost:"d"\n"|&g
close(g,"to")
while(g|&getline)if($0~m){close(g,"from")
split($0,a,r)
return a[f]}}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ awk '{RS="\r";print h("/users/"$0,$0,"/",4),h($2,$2"\\?","<|>",3)}function h(p,m,r,f){d="stackoverflow.com";g="/inet/tcp/0/"d"/80";print"GET "p" HTTP/1.1\nHost:"d"\n"|&g;close(g,"to");while(g|&getline)if($0~m){close(g,"from");split($0,a,r);return a[f]}}' <<< 662504
manatwork 854

bash-4.1$ awk '{RS="\r";print h("/users/"$0,$0,"/",4),h($2,$2"\\?","<|>",3)}function h(p,m,r,f){d="stackoverflow.com";g="/inet/tcp/0/"d"/80";print"GET "p" HTTP/1.1\nHost:"d"\n"|&g;close(g,"to");while(g|&getline)if($0~m){close(g,"from");split($0,a,r);return a[f]}}' <<< 764357
lego-stormtroopr 3,947
```